any ideal $I$ which conatins all finite subsets of $\mathbb \omega $ cannot be a $G_\delta$ set
Let $\omega =\{0,1,2,...\}$
We define the cantor space is the set $2^\omega$ with the following metric:
$$ d(a_n,b_n)=  \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      \frac{1}{m+1} & \mbox{if } m=\min\{k : a_k \neq b_k\} \\
      0 & \mbox{if } \{a_n\} = \{b_n\}  
      \end{array}
\right.$$

Every ideal $I$ on $\omega$ can be treated as a subset of the cantor space $2^\omega$ since $P(\omega)$ and $2^\omega$ can be identified via the characteristic functions.

Now, I read this sentence in an article and I am trying to prove it:

It is easy to check (by the Baire category theorem) that any ideal $I$ which conatins all finite subsets of $\mathbb \omega $ cannot be a $G_\delta$ set.

I did search about the Baire category theorem and I found different forms. But I think the one that I have to use here is :
" Let $X$ be a complete metric space. Then a countable intersection of dense open sets is dense."
We already know that the cantor space is complete so I thought to prove like this:
Let
$$ I = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} G_n$$
Where $G_n$ is open set.
Let $A \in P(\omega)$ and $ \epsilon >0$. then $\exists m \in \mathbb N : \frac{1}{m+1} < \epsilon$
$B:=\{ k \in \omega : k \le m \land k \in A \} $
So $B$ is finit. $\Rightarrow B \in I \Rightarrow B \in G_n (\forall n \in \mathbb N )$
Let $ \alpha \in 2^\omega$ is related to $A$ and $ \beta \in 2^\omega$ is related to $B$
it is clear that $d(\alpha, \beta) \le \frac{1}{m+1} < \epsilon$
then $\beta  \in B_d(\alpha, \epsilon ) $ then $A \in \bar G_n (\forall n \in \mathbb N) \Rightarrow  G_n $ is dense. ($\forall n \in \mathbb N$)
By the Baire category theorem $I$ is dense.
In the first I was thinking that I have to find some problem with being $I$ dense. I tried but I didn't find any problem. Also I realized that since I have taken $B$ from $I$ then $I$ must be dense without even  being $G_\delta $ set. So I can't know how I have to use the Baire category theorem here. Any help?

Even if $I$ were not dense, the Baire theorem only says it wouldn't be a countable intersection of dense open sets, so it still would not have been enough to show $I$ was not $G_\delta$.

@PaulSinclair I know but here I started with assuming that $I$ is $G_\delta $ set. then I proved that since the ideal contains all the finite sets then all  these open sets have to be dense and this is the hypothesis of The Baire Category Theorem. So $I$ must be dense. that was my idea in the first. But I see that when I was trying to prove that these open sets have to be dense I have proved that $I $ is must be dense too. So I can't get any contradiction :(

Hint: Show that $\omega\in I$. If $I$ contains all finite subsets, then it is dense. If $I$ is also $G_\delta$, then $\omega+I$ ($+$ being the symmetric difference) is also dense $G_\delta$. Thus $I\cap (\omega+I)$ is also dense $G_\delta$, in particular non-empty. Thus there exist $A,B\in I$ such that $A=B+\omega$, thus $\omega=A+B\in I$.

Do you mean that $\omega +I=(\omega \cup I ) - (\omega \cap I ) $ ? If it is true I have problem with understanding that. Because $ I \subset \mathcal P (\omega) $ So when $\omega$ is contains the numbers $0,1,2,... $; $I$ is a set of these numbers' sets. So how can I take the union or intersection of them ? For example can we take the union of $A = {1,2,3 }$ and $B ={ {1},{1,2,5 } } $ ? it will not be neither a subset of $\omega $ nor a subset of  $ \mathcal P (\omega)$

with $\omega +I$ I mean the convention ${\omega+A\mid A\in I}$.

I can understand why is $ \omega +I$ is a $G_\delta $ set? Also, if $A=B+\omega$ why it must be $\omega =A+B$ ?For example if we take $A={3,4,5,... } , B={3}$ then $A=B+\omega $ But $A+B ={6,7,8,...} \neq \omega$

The map $2^\omega\rightarrow 2^\omega, A\mapsto A+\omega$ is a homeomorphism (even an isomentry given the metric you presumably mean), thus the image of dense $G_\delta$ sets are again dense $G_\delta$.

This is why it is better to use standard symbolry instead of giving already massively overused symbolry yet another meaning. @A12345 - remember that "+" is being used to represent the symmetric difference of sets. What dialegou is saying is that if $A = B \Delta \omega$, then $A \Delta B = \omega$ (\Delta $\Delta$ is the common symbol for symmetric difference). While this is true in general, it particularly obvious here as all the sets are subsets of $\omega$ and thus the symmetric differences with $\omega$ are just complements.

One can argue that $"+"$ is not given a new meaning here. Identifiyng subsets of $2^\omega$ with functions from $\omega$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$, symmetric difference is nothing but pointwise addition. The use of $\Delta$ obscures that.

@PaulSinclair ok I got it. I haven't seen this symbol "+" as symmetric difference before. I got it now. Thank you

@dialegou thank you very much. I got it now. I just have a one question more $\omega + A = \omega \Delta A = (\omega \cup A) - (\omega \cap A)= \omega - A =A^c $ is that true? Namely $I+\omega $ is the complements of the sets in $I$? Right?

@A12345 that is correct!
